# MySQL query to return duplicated + original records?

Tags: mysql

So I have a table with duplicates and i want to update the original + duplicate values in that table. I can use the **Update** statement to update but I can't seem to figure out a query to return records that include both duplicate and original.

This is the query I'm using:

```
Select primary_id, user_number, duplicate, ignored from myTable 
group by user_number 
having count(user_number) > 1;
```

I have 27 unique user_number and all of them have at least 1 duplicate so I want the query to return at least 54 records (unique + duplicate) but it returns 27 records with unique only.

Goal is to change the values in  **duplicate** and **ignored** columns to **1**.

Once i get all the records I can run the update query below:

```
update myTable 
set duplicate = 1, ignored = 1
```

primary_id is auto incremented id

Comment: Is there no column that distinguishes the rows, like a primary key or a timestamp column?

Comment: actually there is! let me update the question, I just updated the table to include the primary_id which is the auto incremented id so its unique for all

Answer (score 1):

You can use joins in update statements in MySQL.

```
UPDATE myTable AS t1
JOIN myTable AS t2 ON t1.user_number = t2.user_number 
  AND t1.primary_id < t2.primary_id
SET t2.duplicate = 1, t2.ignored = 1;
```

This updates a duplicate row with a greater `primary_id` and the same `user_number` as the first row where that `user_number` occured.

This naturally only affects rows that have duplicates, because if a row `t1` does not have a duplicate, there will not be another row `t2` for it to join to.